# Can't access array item within angular.js view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to access the first item in an array within an angular.js view like this:

```
<p class="name-label">{{user_profile.email[0].emailAddress}}</p>
```

My object looks like this:

```
Object {
....
"email": [
            {
                "emailType": "Primary",
                "emailAddress": "testuser@tp.com"
            }
        ],
....
}
```

This is not working - I don't get an error - it just doesn't display anything!
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: And what it displays if you do simple `{{user_profile}}` ?

Comment: thanks for this. I realised that my userProfile was still wrapped is some weird sessionObject, which didn't seem to be existent when i debugged the object in the console. So I copied the userProfile object into another var and using that inside the view, which eliminated the sessionObject wrap. Really weird. Would really like to understand why this was happening. But working now.

Answer (score 0):

I copied/pasted your code into jsfiddle, and after removing the spurious `Object` and ellipsis it works just fine. Therefore it would appear the problem lies elsewhere.

Perhaps the object isn't structured quite as you expect. Try inserting:

```
<div>{{user_profile.email}}</div>
```

and making sure the output looks like:

```
[{"emailType":"Primary","emailAddress":"testuser@tp.com"}]
```

Another possibility is that you may have put your `<p>` tag outside the tag with the `ng-controller` attribute. If that happens then you would be accessing `user_profile` in the root scope where it probably isn't set.

If none of that works you probably need to edit your question to include more of the surrounding context because right now there isn't enough to give a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. See my comment above. There was some weird stuff happening.